# Need all files created in a folder at 644 permission automatically

Tags: excel, .htaccess, drupal-7

In my site, I am generating reports (custom code) in an excel format. What happens is that it creates the Excel file at a location and then user is supposed to download from there through a link.

The problem is that this file is being created with permission of 600 which means that the user is unable to download it. Is there any way it can have 644 (or higher) permission?

I read that I can place an htaccess file in the folder where the excel file is being created. That htaccess file would ensure that any file created in that folder would have read access. I just don't know what to write in that htaccess file.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ACLS's to set default permissions. Your system also has to have this feature installed. You can use `man acl` for more info.

Say you have a reports directory. Then you would do something like this to set the default permissions.

```
setfacl -d -m g::rwx /reports
setfacl -d -m o::rx /reports
```

This would set permissions on group and other. You can verify with

```
getfacl /reports
```

You can read more about that on this answer.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/how-to-set-default-file-permissions-for-all-folders-files-in-a-directory

and here

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/applying-default-permissions-for-newly-created-files-within-a-specific-folder-605129/